# Call Recorder Issue Unsolved

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have created a Call Recorder app in android. Only problem is it started recording call from the moment I press the call button, although it take some time to get call connected and some more time to get call started. I want it to get recorded right from the moment when call is received, not from where the call is ringing. `OFF_HOOK` is also not showing the correct result. As `OFF_HOOK` is called as soon as I press call button.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(
// LISTEN_ENABLED, 0);
// boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", true);
phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber + "RAVI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (phoneNumber == null) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallRecordService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("commandType", STATE_CALL_START);
        myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallRecordService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("commandType", STATE_CALL_END);
        context.startService(myIntent);

    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        phoneNumber = intent
                .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallRecordService.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("commandType", STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        context.startService(myIntent);

    }
} else {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallRecordService.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("commandType",
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    context.startService(myIntent);
}
}
```

Another Class CallRecordService:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
int commandType = 0;
commandType = intent.getIntExtra("commandType", STATE_CALL_START);
Toast.makeText(this, commandType + "::", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if (commandType == STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER) {
    if (phoneNumber == null)
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
} else if (commandType == STATE_CALL_START) {
    if (phoneNumber == null)
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");

    try {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        myFileName = getFilePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(myFileName);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("Call recorder IllegalStateException: ", "");
        terminateAndEraseFile(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Call recorder Exception: ", "");
        terminateAndEraseFile(2);
    }

    OnErrorListener errorListener = new OnErrorListener() {

        public void onError(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            Log.e("Call recorder OnErrorListener: ", arg1 + "," + arg2);
            arg0.stop();
            arg0.reset();
            arg0.release();
            arg0 = null;
            terminateAndEraseFile(3);
        }

    };
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    OnInfoListener infoListener = new OnInfoListener() {

        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            Log.e("Call recorder OnInfoListener: ", arg1 + "," + arg2);
            arg0.stop();
            arg0.reset();
            arg0.release();
            arg0 = null;
            terminateAndEraseFile(4);
        }

    };
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Receive Start Call",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        manger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_cl5,
                "Call Recording", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("RecordStatus", true);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), 0, intent2, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification Title",
                "Notification Text", contentIntent);
        // manger.notify(0, notification);

        startForeground(1337, notification);

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("Call recorder IllegalStateException: ", "");
        terminateAndEraseFile(5);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Call recorder IOException: ", "");
        terminateAndEraseFile(6);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Call recorder Exception: ", "");
        terminateAndEraseFile(7);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} else if (commandType == STATE_CALL_END) {
    try {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Receiver End Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (manger != null)
        manger.cancel(0);
    stopForeground(true);
    this.stopSelf();
}
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

But its recording from the starting and not from the where call actually starts.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can only detect when the phone starts to make an outgoing call and when the outgoing call is hunged up but you can't determine when a "ringing" is started.

The only workaround is to start recording after the outgoing call starts and passes for some seconds, but then, you're never guaranteed the phone will start ringing:

```
public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        boolean isIncoming;
//Incoming call-   IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when hung up
//Outgoing call-  from IDLE to OFFHOOK when dialed out, to IDLE when hunged up

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
             //incoming call started
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing down on them
            if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
               //outgoing call started
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       //startRecording
                   }
            }, 7000);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //End of call(Idle).  The type depends on the previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                // missed call
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
                  //incoming call ended
            }
            else{
               //outgoing call ended                                              
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Gharteye: Thank you for replying friend. but the problem still remains the same, Recording still starts before the second party picks up the call. And that was my only problem.

Comment: There's no way to detect when the call is picked by the second party, that's why I used the timer logic

Comment: then how do the inbuilt app know,

Comment: Like you say, "inbuilt".  AFAIK, the available APIs don't allow this. I may be wrong though so do research and see if you find a solution